# What is the LINQ Any Query in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, datatable

I want to Check if a DataTable Contains a certain String and then Returns true or false - in C# i would just use the following code but i am not sure how it works in vb.net

```
 var bool = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == "Tobi");
```

Comment: Dim bool As Boolean = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Name") = "Tobi")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Lambda Expressions in VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions)

The equivalent of your statement would be:

```
Dim result = dt.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Name") = "Tobi")
```

LINQ extensions should have parity between C# and VB.NET, as they both come from the same base class library. The syntax for lambdas and generics will be your main difference.

Comment: Also consider using ````String.Compare```` instead, it will be more accurate.

Comment: @JohnPete22 `String.Equals` might be a better choice.

Comment: Potentially.  The only reason I mentioned using a Comparison is the cultures you might be comparing could be different, plus you can ignore casing if you choose.  In reality, it's not a huge difference. I just tend to use a Comparison method when comparing two strings.

Comment: @JohnPete22 Equals has an overload that allows for the same `StringComparison` options.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do.  Make sure you also explicitly declare result as a Boolean, not good practice to just use Object.

And this is just an alternative.  I tend to use SingleOrDefault() quite often, but you could easily use Any() as well (you'd just get rid of the null check at the end)

```
Dim result As Boolean = dt.AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault(Function(r) String.Compare(r.Item("Name"), "Tobi", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0) IsNot Nothing
```

Comment: Omitting the `As Boolean` typically makes no difference as the type will be inferred to `Boolean` (assuming the default `Option Infer On`).

Comment: Aren't you just leaving it to be determined at runtime then what the type is? And we're assuming it will use the correct type, which is most likely will.  But I'd rather be explicit and identify an issue at compile time if there is a type mismatch.

Comment: No, you are not leaving it to be determined at runtime.  You are leaving it to the compiler to determine the type based on the type of the right-hand side expression.  I find that the convenience of not manually giving the type usually outweighs the small chance of having surrounding code depend on the specific type (type inference will still make the variable type `Boolean` so you don't have to worry about it being treated as `Object`) but YMMV.

Comment: I find I make less mistakes when I force the compiler to output the type I intended.  Its a good check that the expression does indeed result in the type I wanted.